# How can i change the price after sale input?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-hooks

I wanna change the value for price after sale based on **price** and **price_sale**

But when i change type value for **price** and not type for **price_sale**, the **price_after_sale** didn't change, and then i type value for **price_sale**, **price_after_sale** changed and it's not the number i expected (maybe the caculation in **changePriceAfterSale** function is wrong). But when I change value for **price_sale** again, the **price_after_sale** is correct.

Here is the code:

```
function ProductCreate() {
  const [checked, setChecked] = useState(false);
  const [price, setPrice] = useState(0);
  const [price_sale, setPrice_sale] = useState(0);
  const [price_after_sale, setPrice_Aftersale] = useState("");
  const changePriceAfterSale = (e) => {
    setPrice_sale(e.target.value);
    setPrice_Aftersale((e.target.value / 100) * price);
  };
  const changePriceAfterSale1 = (e) => {
    setPrice(e.target.value);
    setPrice_Aftersale(e.target.value * (price_sale / 100));
  };
  return (
    <section className="mainList">
      <div className="wrapper">
        <div className="card1">
          <form method="post" /*onSubmit={categoryStore}*/>
            <div className="card-header">
              <strong className="title1">DANH MỤC</strong>
              <div className="button">
                <Link to="/admin/product" className="backward">
                  <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faBackward} />
                  Go back
                </Link>
                <button type="submit" className="save">
                  <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faFloppyDisk} />
                  Save
                </button>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className="form-container grid -bottom-3  ">
              <div className="grid__item large--three-quarters">
                <fieldset className="input-container">
                  <label htmlfor="name">Tên sản phẩm</label>
                  <input
                    name="name"
                    type="text"
                    className="input"
                    id="name"
                    autocomplete="off"
                    //value={name}
                    //onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)}
                    placeholder="Nhập tên danh mục..."
                  />
                </fieldset>
                <fieldset className="input-container">
                  <label htmlfor="name">Đường dẫn xem trước</label>
                  <input
                    name="preview"
                    type="text"
                    className="input"
                    id="name"
                    autocomplete="off"
                    //value={name}
                    //onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)}
                    placeholder="Nhập đường dẫn xem trước..."
                  />
                </fieldset>
                <fieldset className="input-container">
                  <label htmlfor="metakey">Từ khóa</label>
                  <input
                    name="metakey"
                    type="text"
                    className="input"
                    id="name"
                    autocomplete="off"
                    //value={metakey}
                    //onChange={(e) => setMetakey(e.target.value)}
                    placeholder="Nhập từ khóa..."
                  />
                </fieldset>
                <fieldset className="input-container">
                  <label htmlfor="metadesc">Mô tả</label>
                  <textarea
                    name="metadesc"
                    className="input1textarea"
                    id="name"
                    //value={metadesc}
                    //onChange={(e) => setMetadesc(e.target.value)}
                    placeholder="Nhập mô tả..."
                  />
                </fieldset>
              </div>
              <div className="grid__item large--one-quarter">
                <fieldset className="input-container">
                  <label htmlfor="parent_id">Danh mục</label>
                  <select
                    name="category_id"
                    className="input"
                    //value={parent_id}
                    //onChange={(e) => setParent_id(e.target.value)}
                  >
                    <option value="0" selected disabled>
                      --Chọn danh mục--
                    </option>
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                    <option value="2">2</option>
                  </select>
                </fieldset>

                {/* Start from here */}
                {/* Start from here */}
                {/* Start from here */}

                <fieldset className="input-container">
                  <label htmlfor="price">Giá sản phẩm</label>
                  <input
                    name="price"
                    type="text"
                    className="input"
                    id="name"
                    value={price}
                    onChange={changePriceAfterSale1}
                    placeholder="Nhập giá sản phẩm..."
                    autocomplete="off"
                  />
                </fieldset>
                <fieldset className="input-container">
                  <label htmlfor=".price-check">
                    <input
                      type="checkbox"
                      checked={checked}
                      onChange={() => {
                        if (checked) {
                          setPrice_sale("");
                        }
                        setChecked(!checked);
                      }}
                    />
                    <span>Giá sale? (%)</span>
                  </label>
                  <div className="price-check">
                    <input
                      name="price_sale"
                      type="text"
                      className="input-price"
                      id="name"
                      disabled={!checked}
                      value={(() => {
                        if (price_sale === 0) return 0;
                        else return price_sale;
                      })()}
                      onChange={changePriceAfterSale}
                      placeholder="Tỉ lệ sale..."
                      autocomplete="off"
                    />
                    <input
                      name="price_after_sale"
                      type="text"
                      className="input-price-check"
                      value={price_after_sale}
                      id="name"
                      disabled
                      placeholder="0"
                    />
                  </div>
                </fieldset>

                {/* End here */}
                {/* End here */}
                {/* End here */}

                <fieldset className="input-container">
                  <label htmlfor="qty">Số lượng</label>
                  <input
                    name="qty"
                    type="number"
                    min="0"
                    className="input"
                    id="name"
                    autocomplete="off"
                    //value={name}
                    //onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)}
                    placeholder="Nhập số lượng  ..."
                  />
                </fieldset>
                <fieldset className="input-container">
                  <label htmlfor="image">Hình ảnh phía trước</label>
                  <input
                    name="image"
                    type="file"
                    className="input"
                    id="image"
                  />
                </fieldset>
                <fieldset className="input-container">
                  <label htmlfor="back_image">Hình ảnh phía sau</label>
                  <input
                    name="back_image"
                    type="file"
                    className="input"
                    id="image"
                  />
                </fieldset>
                <fieldset className="input-container">
                  <label htmlfor="status">Tình trạng xuất bản</label>
                  <select
                    name="status"
                    className="input"
                    //value={status}
                    //onChange={(e) => setStatus(e.target.value)}
                  >
                    <option disabled>--Chọn tình trạng xuất bản--</option>
                    <option value="1">Xuất bản</option>
                    <option value="2">Không xuất bản</option>
                  </select>
                </fieldset>
              </div>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  );
}

export default ProductCreate;
```

What i expected it to be: When **price** or **price_sale** change, **price_after_sale** change and caculation must be correct